# Microsoft Platform Ready Test fails security test with .NET performance counters

Tags: c#, .net, acl

We are doing a Microsoft Platform Ready test on Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V VM. The application being tested is a .NET application. The test fails with security issues. The "Attack Surface Report" reports two Severity Level 1 errors with heading "Memory Mapped Sections With Weak ACLs".
The errors are against .NET performance counters.

- ACL on section \BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0.net CLR networking allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.
- ACL on section \BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0servicemodelservice 3.0.0.0 allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.

How do I fix these errors?

Below are the error details.

- ACL on section `\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0.net` CLR networking allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.

  - Description:

    - The ACL on section `\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0.net` CLR networking allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.
  - Details:

    - Section: `\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0.net` CLR networking
  - Account Rights

    - Authenticated Users `(S-1-5-11) SECTION_MAP_WRITE`
  - The following processes were found to have an open handle to this section:

    - `<Application Name.exe>`
  - Action:

    - The ACL must be tightened.
- ACL on section `\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0servicemodelservice 3.0.0.0` allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.

  - Description:

    - The ACL on section `\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0servicemodelservice 3.0.0.0` allows tampering by by multiple non-administrator accounts.
  - Details:

    - Section:`\BaseNamedObjects\netfxcustomperfcounters.1.0servicemodelservice 3.0.0.0`
  - Account Rights

    - Authenticated Users `(S-1-5-11) SECTION_MAP_WRITE`
  - The following processes were found to have an open handle to this section:

    - `<Application Name.exe>`
  - Action:

    - The ACL must be tightened.

Answer (score 1):

Your installer is creating files that anyone can overwrite. This means an attacker could conceivably replace these .Dll files with ones of their own. The usual solution is to have the installer set tighter permissions on the file, either set it to modifiable by admins only or setting it read-only period.

[Similar case](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6ff4f78e-5840-48e6-a97f-5f28ac46e86a/windows-security-best-practices-test-failed-in-windows-ack-test-on-win8?forum=windowscompatibility)

[Technical Description of Access Masks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2010/04/01/about-the-access-mask-structure.aspx)

Comment: This is not about files, but a shared memory segment which is opened behind the scenes (by .NET) when an application accesses performance counters.